# La conversión especificada no es válida ComboBox - Vb.NET

Tags: vb.net, .net

Quiero llenar un combobox con registros de una base de datos pero me sale un error en el Exception del Try, he intentado de todo, hasta formatear el arreglo del DataReader en String, solo no funciona con el combobox, con un listview si funciona a la perfección

```
Dim cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\servidoracrec\acrec$\Pacientes.mdb")



Public Sub obtener_paciente()
    cn.Close()
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT Paciente.ApellidoPaterno, Paciente.ApellidoMaterno, Paciente.Nombre FROM Paciente;", cn)
    Dim rd As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    Dim nom As String
    Dim am As String
    Dim ap As String

    Try
        cn.Open()
        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While rd.Read
            If IsDBNull(rd(0)) Then
                ap = ""
            Else
                ap = rd(0).ToString
            End If

            If IsDBNull(rd(1)) Then
                am = ""
            Else
                am = rd(1).ToString
            End If
            If IsDBNull(rd(2)) Then
                nom = ""
            Else
                nom = rd(2).ToString
            End If
            Nombre.Items.Add(ap & " " & am & " " & nom)
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        'cn.Close()
    End Try
    cn.Close()
End Sub
```

Yo no hice la base de datos, pero no creo que tenga algo que ver porque  los campos están en Texto y en NotNull

Comment: muchas gracias por sus respuestas, la solución realmente era extremadamente fácil, solo cambié el tipo de combobox, tenía DropDown y lo cambié por DropDownList y asunto arreglado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para cargar un combo lo mejor es usar clases, podrias definir algo como ser

```
Public Class Paciente
    Public Property Nombre As String
    Public Property ApellidoMaterno As String
    Public Property ApellidoPaterno As String
End Class
```

y luego cargar una lista

```
Public Sub obtener_paciente() As List(Of Paciente)

    Dim lista As New List(Of Paciente)

    Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\servidoracrec\acrec$\Pacientes.mdb")
        cn.Close()

        Dim query As String = "SELECT Paciente.ApellidoPaterno, Paciente.ApellidoMaterno, Paciente.Nombre FROM Paciente"
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, cn)

        Dim rd As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While rd.Read
            Dim item As Paciente
            item.Nombre = Convert.ToString(rd("Nombre"))
            item.ApellidoPaterno = Convert.ToString(rd("ApellidoPaterno"))
            item.ApellidoMaterno = Convert.ToString(rd("ApellidoMaterno"))
        End While

    End Using

    Return lista

End Sub
```

entonces lo usarias

```
Try

    Dim lista As List(Of Paciente) = obtener_paciente()

    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Nombre"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Nombre"
    ComboBox1.DataSource = lista

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

es importante el uso del `using` para definir la conexion y asi evitas problemas al definir las operaciones de open y close

sino quieres repetir el connection string deberias definirlo en el app.config